# Matlab GUIDE GUI Handles change in values after using Load() function?

Tags: handle, matlab-guide, matlab-load

Inside a GUI that I have made using GUIDE in Matlab. I run into a problem where upon using the Load() function to load a .MAT file all my handles change values. This means that if I had a button that I wanted to use on my GUI. My program will believe its handle is for example

```
 handles.button1 =190.082
```

when in reality the only way I can access that button any more is through a different handle that is unknown. So if its unknown lets see what its new handle must be.

```
findobj('Tag','button1') = 227.0093
```

As you can see these numbers are completely different. Why the handles values get changed is beyond me. Since the handles change I can no longer use the set() function as I have written in previous sections of code. For example I have to change

```
set(handles.button1, 'Enable', 'off');

to 

set(findobj('Tag','button1'),'Enable','off');
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this problem occurs when using `Load()`?
Is there a feasible solution instead of having to find the handle for an object every time you want to use it?

Comment: Why are you loading the handle values? It is normal that they would change.

Comment: I apologize if that's how you interpreted my question. I am not loading the handle values using Load(). I am using Load() to load in some external variables from another program. Upon using the Load() function. My program changes all its handles.

Comment: It is probably because there is a handles structure in your .mat file. Do not load it, or remove it from the .mat file.

Comment: Yes thank you HebeleHododo. I was unaware of the .mat also having the handles. Well I think I have felt silly enough today.

Answer (score 0):

The .MAT file conveniently also had a handles variable in it which overwrote my current handles.